# Is there a way to stop the avplayer sending a range http header field

Tags: ios, audio-streaming, avplayer

If you load remote files with the AVPlayer it sends a http request with a range field in the request header, something like

```
Range: bytes=0-8148096
```

I like to use the SevenDigital commercial API for streaming songs but they cannot handle this Range header. Is there a way to change the URL requests the AVPlayer sends?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, and it is an apple standard that media providers need to support http 1.1 with the range header (check out the iTunes store guidelines for podcasts for example), so I wouldn't expect it anytime soon.  You'll need to roll your own here, sorry.